# Running chromedriver Through Django Selenium Testing

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

It seems that a lof of people are having trouble getting Selenium to find chromedriver, so this may apply to them aswell if they actually have the chromedriver.exe in the correct path.

It seems I have everything I need to have these selenium tests working, and when I manually try running the following 2 lines, everything works fine (it finds chromedriver and opens Chrome).

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Chrome()
```

However, when I put the exact same code into a Django test and try running the test through Django, I get a "ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path" error. I've tried re-installing Django and Selenium to no success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually caused by enabling Celery tasks.